# como solucionar esto java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, mysql, excel

hola estoy subiendo un archivo de excel a jsp para guardarlo en MySQL el archivo de excel tiene dos campos tipo fecha, al momento de leer el respectivo archivo me sale este  error **java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date** al ejecutarlo y no he podido solucionarlo alguien sabe como puedo arreglar esto 
subo el código en donde estoy leyendo el archivo de excel, los casos en donde evaluo los dos campos tipo fecha son el 3 y el 4 no se como se puede evaluar en esta parte tampoco

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= firstsheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        fila = firstsheet.getRow(i);
        No = new TablaNovedadEmpleado();
        No.setFecha(fecha);

        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < fila.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            Cell celda = fila.getCell(j);
            if (j == 0) {
                if (celda == null || celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            switch (j) {

                case 1:
                    if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        No.setNombres(celda.getStringCellValue());
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        No.setTipo_Novedad(celda.getStringCellValue());
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        No.setFecha_inicio((Date) celda.getDateCellValue());

                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                        No.setFecha_fin((Date) celda.getDateCellValue());
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        No.setDias(celda.getStringCellValue());
                    }
                    break;
                case 6:
                    if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        No.setHoras(celda.getStringCellValue());
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
        if (No.getNombres() != null) {
            lst.add(No);

            //guardarArchivoNoveddades(No);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(lst, TablaNovedadEmpleado.comparet);
```

Answer (score 5):

El error indica el problema:

> java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

estas enviando un dato de tipo de `java.util.Date` pero se espera recibir `java.sql.Date`

me parece que el problema surge en estas lineas de código:

```
 No.setFecha_inicio((Date) celda.getDateCellValue());
 
 No.setFecha_fin((Date) celda.getDateCellValue());
```

lo que puedes realizar es crear un nuevo objeto de tipo `java.util.Date` que representa el mismo valor que el `java.sql.Date`

por ejemplo:

```
No.setFecha_inicio(new java.sql.Date(((Date) celda.getDateCellValue()).getTime()));
```

y

```
No.setFecha_fin(new java.sql.Date(((Date) celda.getDateCellValue()).getTime()));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me dio

Comment: Que bien Victor, solo necesitabas enviar el valor adecuado, en este caso de tipo java.sql.Date. ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score -1):

Para pasar de **`java.util.Date`** a **`java.sql.Date`** debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
java.util.Date dateUtil=new java.util.Date("22/08/2020");                                                

java.sql.Date dateSql= new java.sql.Date(dateUtil.getDay(),dateUtil.getMonth(),dateUtil.getYear());
```

Comment: El constructor de `java.util.Date` que acepta una cadena está marcado como obsoleto, así como también los métodos `getDay()`, `getMonth()` y `getYear()`. Usar estos getters también ignora la información de la hora.