# Error Cannot convert 27/02/17 12:00 AM of type class java.util.Date to class java.sql.Date

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Necesito Orientación, tengo este formulario xhtml con primefaces y quiero almacenar fecha y hora desde el componente calendar a mi MySql como resuelvo el error:

> ```
>  javax.el.ELException: /create.xhtml @44,91 value="#{data.kardex_create.fechaingreso}:
>  Cannot convert 27/02/17 12:00 AM of type class java.util.Date to class java.sql.Date"
> ```

El código:

**create.xhtml**

```
<!-- 
< ?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
< html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
       xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
     < h:head>
        < meta charset="utf-8"/>
        < link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        < script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        < title>JSF Fecha y Hora</title>
    < /h:head>
    < h:body>
        < div class="container">
        < div class="row">
            < h3>JSF Fecha y hora</h3>
        < /div>
        < div class="row">
            < div class="tabbable">
                < ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    < li class="active"><a href="" data-toggle="tab">JSF</a>< /li>                        
                < /ul>                    
            < /div>
        </div>    
        < div class="row">
            < h4>Agregar Fecha y Hora< /h4>
        < /div>
        < div class="row">
            < h:form class="form-horizontal">
            < div class="control-group">
            < p:outputLabel class="control-label" value="FECHA INGRESO:"/>
            < div class="controls"> 
            < p:calendar id="xfingreso" value="#{data.kardex_create.fechaingreso}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true"
                                    required="true" requiredMessage="Ingresar Fecha"/>
                  <h:outputText value="#{data.kardex_create.fechaingreso}">
                   </h:outputText>
                        <h:message for="xfingreso" style="color:red"/>
                    </div> 
                </div>

                < div class="control-group">
                     <p:outputLabel class="control-label" value="HORA INGRESO:"/>
                    < div class="controls">
                        < p:calendar id="xhingreso" value="#{data.kardex_create.horaingreso}" pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true"
                                    required="true" requiredMessage="Ingresar Hora"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{data.kardex_create.horaingreso}">
                        </h:outputText>
                        <h:message for="xhingreso" style="color:red"/>
                   </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <h:commandLink class="btn btn-success" action="#{data.create()}">Guardar</h:commandLink>  
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="btn" href="index.xhtml">Cancelar</a>
                </div>
            </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>

-->
```

**ManagedBeanData.java**

```
import dto.Calificador;
import dto.Kardex;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import model.dao.DaoCalificador;
import model.dao.DaoKardex;
import model.dao.impl.DaoKardexImpl;

@ManagedBean(name = "data")
@RequestScoped
public class ManagedBeanData {

private Integer kardex_id;
private List<Kardex> kardex_list; 
private Kardex kardex_create;

public ManagedBeanData() {
    kardex_create = new Kardex();
}

//GETTER Y SETTER DE IDS
public Integer getTipoacto_id() {
    return tipoacto_id;
}

public void setTipoacto_id(Integer tipoacto_id) {
    this.tipoacto_id = tipoacto_id;
}

public Integer getCalificador_id() {
    return calificador_id;
}

public void setCalificador_id(Integer calificador_id) {
    this.calificador_id = calificador_id;
}

public Integer getKardex_id() {
    return kardex_id;
}

public void setKardex_id(Integer kardex_id) {
    this.kardex_id = kardex_id;
}


//GETTER DE LOS LIST 

public List<Kardex> getKardex_list() {
    DaoKardex daoKardex = new DaoKardexImpl();
    kardex_list = daoKardex.kardexQRY();
    return kardex_list;
}

//METODOS PARA EL CRUD

public Kardex getKardex_create() {
    return kardex_create;
}

public void setKardex_create(Kardex kardex_create) {
    this.kardex_create = kardex_create;
}

public String create(){
    DaoKardex daoKardex = new DaoKardexImpl();
    daoKardex.kardexINS(kardex_create);
    return "index";
}

}
```

**DaoKardexImpl.java**

```
import dto.Kardex;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import model.dao.DaoKardex;
import sql.ConectaDB;

public class DaoKardexImpl implements DaoKardex {

    private ConectaDB db;

    public DaoKardexImpl() {
        this.db = new ConectaDB();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Kardex> kardexQRY() {
        List<Kardex> list = null;
        Connection cn = db.getConnection();
        String cmdSQL = "select k.nrokardex, k.fechaingreso, k.horaingreso, k.contratante, "
                + "t.nombreacto, cal.nombreapellidos from kardex k inner join tipoacto t on"
                + "k.idtipoacto = t.idtipoacto inner join calificador cal on "
                + "k.idcalificador = cal.idcalificador order by idkardex desc;";

        if (cn != null) {
            try {
                Statement st = cn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(cmdSQL);
                list = new ArrayList<>();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    Kardex k = new Kardex();
                    k.setNrokardex(rs.getString(1));
                    k.setFechaingreso(rs.getDate(2));
                    k.setHoraingreso(rs.getTime(3));
                    k.setContratante(rs.getString(4));
                    k.setIdtipoacto(rs.getInt(5));
                    k.setIdcalificador(rs.getInt(6));
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    cn.close();
                } catch (SQLException en) {
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public String kardexINS(Kardex kardex) {
        String result = null;
        Connection cn = db.getConnection();
        String cmdSQL = "insert into kardex (nrokardex, fechaingreso, horaingreso, contratante, idtipoacto, idcalificador) "
                + "values ('?','?','?','?','?','?');";

        if (cn != null) {
            try {
                PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(cmdSQL);
                pst.setString(1, kardex.getNrokardex());
                pst.setDate(2, kardex.getFechaingreso());
                pst.setTime(3, kardex.getHoraingreso());
                pst.setString(4, kardex.getContratante());
                pst.setInt(5, kardex.getIdtipoacto());
                pst.setInt(6, kardex.getIdcalificador());

                int n = pst.executeUpdate();

                if (n == 0) {
                    result = "0 filas afectadas";
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                result = e.getMessage();
            } finally {
                try {
                    cn.close();
                } catch (SQLException en) {
                    result = en.getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**DaoKardex.java**

```
import dto.Kardex;
import java.util.List;

public interface DaoKardex {

    public List<Kardex> kardexQRY();

    public String kardexINS(Kardex kardex);

}
```

**Kardex.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;

public class Kardex implements Serializable{

    private Integer idkardex;
    private Date fechaingreso;
    private Time horaingreso;

    public Kardex() {
    }

    public Kardex(Integer idkardex, Date fechaingreso, Time horaingreso) {
        this.idkardex = idkardex;
        this.fechaingreso = fechaingreso;
        this.horaingreso = horaingreso;

    }

    public Integer getIdkardex() {
        return idkardex;
    }

    public void setIdkardex(Integer idkardex) {
        this.idkardex = idkardex;
    }

    public Date getFechaingreso() {
        return fechaingreso;
    }

    public void setFechaingreso(Date fechaingreso) {
        this.fechaingreso = fechaingreso;
    }

    public Time getHoraingreso() {
        return horaingreso;
    }

    public void setHoraingreso(Time horaingreso) {
        this.horaingreso = horaingreso;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar una conversion de `java.util.Date` a `java.sql.Date` lo podemos realizar de la siguiente forma

```
java.sql.Date fechaSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(fechaUtilDate.getTime());
```

para esto puedes hacer uso de un metodo para realizar la conversion

```
public java.sql.Date convertir(java.util.Date fechaUtilDate){
    return new java.sql.Date(fechaUtilDate.getTime());
}
```

---

Es un caso similar a este

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827827/cannot-convert-17-04-16-0000-of-type-class-java-util-date-to-class-java-sql-dat

Una pregunta similar

[como solucionar esto java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44998/como-solucionar-esto-java-util-date-cannot-be-cast-to-java-sql-date)

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar de `java.util.Date` a `java.sql.Date` lo más fácil es usar el constructor a partir de la fecha en milisegundos:

```
public java.sql.Date convertir(java.util.Date fecha){
    return new java.sql.Date(fecha.getTime());
}
```

El método `getTime()` devuelve la fecha en milisegundos, y es común a ambas clases (`java.sql.Date` hereda de `java.util.Date`).

Answer (score 0):

La clase `java.sql.Date` es subclase de `java.util.Date`. En un modelo deberías usar `java.util.Date`.

En `Kardex` cambia:

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

a

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Un `Date` en SQL tiene que ser normalizado para tener horas, minutos, segundos y milisegundos colocado a 0. Tienes que tomar esto en cuenta donde tienes que convertir de java.sql.Date a java.util.Date.

Probablemente más facil sería de trabajar en la BBDD con un sello de tiempo (`java.sql.Timestamp`) que consiges con `rs.getTimestamp()` y trabajar con una fecha completa.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la conversión de `java.util.Date` a `java.sql.Date` de la siguiente forma:

```
//Estableces el formato que pide el método valueOf
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
//La transformas desde ese formato como cadena
java.sql.Date fechaFinal = java.sql.Date.valueOf(sdf.format(fechaOrigen)
```

Con `fechaFinal` ya puedes operar como tipo `java.sql.Date`.